# Linphone erro de compilação no ./prepare.py

Tags: android, cmake

Baixei do git o projeto do linphone, instalei todas dependências necessárias e configurei tudo certinho ( acredito eu )
mas ao executar o comando

```
./prepare.py
```

o mesmo encerra no meio da compilação neste ponto

```
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Using toolchain file '/home/jasar/StudioProjects/linphone-android/submodules/cmake-builder/toolchains/toolchain-android-arm.cmake'
-- Using configuration file '/home/jasar/StudioProjects/linphone-android/submodules/cmake-builder/configs/config-android.cmake'
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.9") 
CMake Error at cmake/CheckBuildTools.cmake:147 (message):
  Could not find the pkg-config program.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  builders/CMakeLists.txt:66 (include)
  configs/config-android.cmake:61 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:67 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/jasar/StudioProjects/linphone-android/WORK/android-arm/cmake/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
```

segue o log do cmakeoutput ->
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=42144343558195282206

alguém por gentileza poderia me orientar sobre o assunto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta rodar este comando no terminal como root ou utilizando o sudo

```
apt-get install pkg-config -y
```

depois usa

```
./perape.py --list-features
```

se listar as features então já pode ser compilado sem erros.

Comment: realmente funcionou, rsss agora vou continuar aqui obrigado. vamos ao prox problema ^